# Why isn't my schema.rb file updated?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, database-schema

I recently looked at my schema.rb file and was alarmed to find that certain columns that do exist in my database do not appear, and some tables are missing entirely. The missing columns were added to the database through "def change add_column" migrations, though some columns that were added in that way do appear as expected in schema.rb.

On closer inspection, I realized that schema.rb has not been updated since I created the Users table.

20151019205241_create_users.rb:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

This has not caused an issue for me in practice, but I thought schema.rb was supposed to be kept automatically updated, and that it would be important to have it updated in order to recreate the database. Can anyone help me figure out why it would not be updating?

One possibility is that it stopped being updated when I switched my database from sqlite3 to postgresql. I don't remember exactly, but I think the timing makes sense.

Comment: Not sure how switching the database interferes with `schema.rb`. Does the file get updated correctly when you do a `rake db:migrate` now? (You don't need to add any new migrations for this Rake task to run successfully.)

Comment: It did not. Next time I update the database in some way I will test this out. For now @smefju's solution below worked. Thanks for your reply! You're right, it does not appear to have anything to do with switching databases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `rake db:schema:dump` to re-create the file from the current database structure.

Schema file is independent from the driver so migrating from sqlite3 to PostgreSQL shouldn't matter. Make sure that `version` for definition in the file is not greater than current the current date. You can also add the whole file to the question's snippet.